# Chrome Extension sandbox

Tags: google-chrome

i use manifest 2.

manifest.json

```
{
...
"manifest_version": 2,
...
"sandbox": {
"pages": ["options.html"]
},
 "browser_action" : {
  ...
  "default_popup" : "popup.html"
}
...
}
```

popup.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@ui_locale");
</script>
```

i get this error.
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getMessage' of undefined"
Why?

Answer (score 0):

I found this error too.

On popup.html, this error happens. On option.html page, chrome.i18n looks good but bad again if used in iframe.

Try

```
if(chrome.i18n)
{
    return chrome.i18n.getMessage(msg)
}
else
{
    return ...
}
```

Same discussion on 
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-apps/csLpa0ndqjo